# Ubuntu can't read my USB: "device descriptor read/64, error -110"

Tags: 14.04, usb

I have a 16GB flash drive. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.
I can't open my flash drive and I can't see it in GParted. 
After running `tail -f /var/log/syslog` .
After inserting my flash:

```
USB disconnect, device number 10
Jul  3 16:39:55 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3309.712166] usb 2-3: new high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
Jul  3 16:39:55 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3309.846591] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000
Jul  3 16:39:55 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3309.846601] usb 2-3: 

New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
    Jul  3 16:39:55 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3309.846609] usb 2-3: Product: Silicon-Power
    Jul  3 16:39:55 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3309.846615] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: UFD 2.0
    Jul  3 16:39:55 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3309.846622] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 1401208423400131
    Jul  3 16:39:55 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3309.847176] usb-storage 2-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
    Jul  3 16:39:55 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3309.847309] scsi12 : usb-storage 2-3:1.0
    Jul  3 16:39:55 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 11: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3"
    Jul  3 16:39:55 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 11 was not an MTP device
    Jul  3 16:40:17 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3332.176107] usb 2-3: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
    Jul  3 16:40:33 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3347.288080] usb 2-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
    Jul  3 16:40:48 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3362.504081] usb 2-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
    Jul  3 16:40:48 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3362.720076] usb 2-3: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
    Jul  3 16:40:52 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3366.812110] usb 2-3: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
    Jul  3 16:41:07 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3381.924082] usb 2-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
    Jul  3 16:41:23 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3397.356093] usb 2-3: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
    Jul  3 16:41:38 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3412.468057] usb 2-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
    Jul  3 16:41:54 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3428.664065] usb 2-3: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
    Jul  3 16:42:09 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3443.776100] usb 2-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
    Jul  3 16:42:24 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3458.992085] usb 2-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
    Jul  3 16:42:25 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3459.208063] usb 2-3: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
    Jul  3 16:42:40 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3474.320039] usb 2-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
    Jul  3 16:42:50 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3484.516109] usb 2-3: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
    Jul  3 16:42:50 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3484.768108] usb 2-3: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
Jul  3 16:43:05 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3499.880081] usb 2-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Jul  3 16:43:20 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3515.096081] usb 2-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Jul  3 16:43:21 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3515.312048] usb 2-3: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
Jul  3 16:43:36 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3530.424032] usb 2-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Jul  3 16:43:46 rihanna-VGN-Z56GG-B kernel: [ 3540.505230] scsi 12:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
```

Answer (score 21):

So the error is `device descriptor read/64, error -110` which is basically has something to do  with power. Your laptop/desktop was not able to supply enough power to the USB.

A solution that has worked for many is shutting down the system, unplug the charger and USB for 5 minutes, replug charger and USB, restart the system.

See:

- [usb - device descriptor read/64, error -110 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653692/device-descriptor-read-64-error-110)
- [[SOLVED] USB 2/3 device descriptor read64, error -110](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1610142)

Comment: I restarted the system and tested in on Windows. It didn't work there too.

Comment: In windows on another computer? Did you *disconnect* the power supply or just hit restart?

Comment: In Windows On another PC. I read the answers in links you mentioned. I disconnected all other USB devices.

Comment: I could not believe it a single second but that actually worked like a charm. Just unplugged the power cable for 1 or 2 minutes and Ubuntu started in seconds instead of a minute because I had this issue at startup.

Comment: Indeed, my USB hub was plugged to USB 3.1 but I forgot to toggle my power socket hub on. The error appeared 3 times at 16s interval. After a while though, my laptop finally booted by itself. Maybe it managed to provide power from its remaining battery or something.

Answer (score 8):

Unplugging everything worked for me. See [my stackoverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40156220/1410125) on the thread 1) mentioned by Ron, copied/pasted here below:

I was running into "error -110" messages for my Inateck dual bay USB 3.0 to SATA device ([amazon link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00N1KXE9K)). This fixed it for me:

1. `shutdown -h now` (turn off the computer)
2. Unplug USB device from computer.
3. Unplug power cord to back of the computer.
4. Unplug power to Inateck - pull wall wart plug **from wall socket**.
5. Noticed there was a green glowing LED on the Inateck wall wart; waited for that to go dark.
6. Waited ~3min total.
7. Plugged everything back in and booted up.

Worked liked a charm.

**Note**: Previously I tried just unplugging the computer and letting it sit for a while; that didn't work. I had to unplug the USB from the computer and the usb device power adapter from the wall.

Must be something with USB power provisioning/negotiation?

Answer (score 5):

The `device descriptor read/64, error -110` means that USB port power supply was exceeded.  Try again using all of the other sockets.

See also the answers on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653692/device-descriptor-read-64-error-110) and [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/719302/trying-to-restore-data-usb-drive-not-properly-detected).

Comment: Although I had `device descriptor read/64, error -71` , this helped me!

Answer (score 1):

Having struggled with this error for a long time, up until the machine became nearly unbootable, could not restart and showed all kind of erratic behaviour.
I checked the innerparts and found a faulty hardiskconnector. 
The sata-mold appeared to be broken.
After replacing the connector all is well!
So, it does not have to be a faulty usb port at all.

Answer (score 1):

On my machine, this occurs randomly every 3-5 days. Today I was able to fix the issue without reboot by first plugging out all USB-connectors, then waiting for some time (maybe ~a minute). Then I replugged the connectors in first to the USB-2 connectors. The issue persisted. Then I detached the connectors, and attached them to USB 3 connectors which probably have different bus/chipset, and managed to get the devices to work (mouse, keyboard).